# Summing Duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a long list of names of products and numbers of those products, I want to combine all the duplicate entries and add their numbers. So if I have 2 entries for Widget X, and each entry has 3 products, then I want to combine this to one entry for Widget X with 6 products.

I've sorted the list out and summed them for each product but I just used a sum function, I felt there must be a formula that uses an IF statement to detect entries that equal each other and then sum their respective quantity lines but I can't figure it out.

What i'm trying to get is IF (any field in column A = 3792 , then sum all its associated quantity fields in column C)

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    2
3792    Widget A    1
3805    Widget B    1
3805    Widget B    1
3806    Widget C    8
3823    Widget D    895
3823    Widget D    1
3823    Widget D    20
3892    Widget E    2
3892    Widget E    1
3892    Widget E    1
```

Comment: @Stewbob: I think it's in the right place. It has to do with formulas and formulas are some kind of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel's [SUMIF()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php)-Formula might help you accomplish this.

as described, the syntax is

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)
```

Searches fields within `range` that match `criteria` and sums up the values in `sum_range` (at the same index where the criteria has been found in range, respectively).

you might want to create a matrix for each number/search criteria to sum up and compare...

**Another approach**:

For a certain Column (let's take C) make a temporary column and add a 1 as value to each line.

For example, in Column "Sum A:" type the formula:

```
=IF($A2=D$1,1,0)
```

Whereas D1 is the cell containing the number 3792 (in top) and the 2 in C2 is the current line the formula stands in.

You would just be able to drag it to the right and to the bottom.

This would be the result:

```
A       B           C         D         E         F         G
                    3792      3805      3806      3823      3892
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3792    Widget A    1
3805    Widget B              1
3805    Widget B              1
3806    Widget C                       1
3823    Widget D                                  1
3823    Widget D                                  1
3823    Widget D                                  1
3892    Widget E                                            1
3892    Widget E                                            1
3892    Widget E                                            1

SUM:                7         2        1          3         3
```

You just simply sum up at the end and you got your results. If another number should be added than `1`, simply add another column containing the appropriate value, you then replace it in the `IF`-formula.

you might want to automate this even more using a `HLOOKUP()` for the widget number's at the top.

regards

Comment: I've got =SUMIF(A:A,3792,C:C ) this sums for each product code entered in the criteria field. I'll look into matrices to see if I can get make a fully automated list. Great answer, much appreciated.

Comment: np. I'm not talking about Excel-Matrices. I've edited my response to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Use the sumif function. See [this blog](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) for an explanation.

Assuming the values started in A1, paste this function into D1 and copy to D1-D16 to get sums for each field (there would of course be duplicates)

```
=SUMIF(A$1:A$16,A1,C$1:C$16)
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I just looked at the first answer that came along, I would accept your answer too if I could for more than one.

Comment: actually mine was the first answer by a full 13 seconds, still never mind

Comment: oh right, the second answer must have been voted up then, it was just the first one I'd seen

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the list sorted, I would use the builtin SUBTOTAL feature instead of a formula. Select all your data then goto Data > Subtotal Then have it based off of change in product.

The other option is to create a pivot table that will sum the items. I'm a big fan of keeping summary and data separate.

Answer (score 0):

The original post was from 7 years ago but here is my approach anyways using slightly more brute force.

I took all of "Column A" and copy pasted into a new sheet (or to the right or somewhere out of the way). Highlighted the copied set of data and removed duplicates leaving a new list of just single instances of values from "Column A". Lets call this new data set "Column D". Then let's call the totals column  "Column E"

I then used SUMPRODUCT in conjunction with SUMIF in "Column E" to get a formula like this:

**Column E value**=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(**Original Column A Range**,**Lookup value in question from the Column D**,**Original Column C ranges**))

This will sum all the instances and output a grand total.

Obvious issues with this are the results will not auto update to include new instances of "Column A" but if you have an existing set of data that you want to extract from could be helpful as a quick solution.

JD

Answer (score 0):

Excel can automatically handle this using the consolidate tool on the data tools section of the data ribbon tab.

Just create a new sheet, then reference your cell range with counts, hit the left column check box, and it should give you a unique consolidated count.

Answer (score 0):

The way I sum duplicates is:

Say you've got something like this

```
    A      B        D
    France Apples   15
    Spain  Potatoes 15
    France Apples   5
    Spain  Potatoes 1
```

I would do (in column D):

```
    =A2&"-"&B2
```

Then copy column D to column E and remove duplicates.

In column F:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((D$2:D$5=E2)*C$2:C$5)
```

This way you should have in column E:

```
    D               E 
    France-Apples   20
    Spain-Potatoes  16
```